# Magento2 Password Reset Query Not working

Tags: magento2, password-recovery

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

this above query is not working

Answer (score 0):

Right Answer is

For Magento 1.9 and older:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = md5('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD'), is_active = 1 WHERE `username` = 'YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME';
```

For Magento 2

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxYOUR_NEW_PASSWORD', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE `username` = 'YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME';
```